# find a number between a range of numbers

Tags: python, unix, sed, awk

I have a file1 that has ranges like this

> 10 20
>
> 50 60
>
> 70 100
>
> 150 170
>
> ....
>
> ....

file2

> 15
>
> 55
>
> 80
>
> 160
>
> ....
>
> ....

i want to read the ranges in the file1 and look in file2 and get the values between them

final output:

> 15 is the value between 10 and 20
>
> 55 is the value between 50 and 60
>
> ....
>
> ....

Comment: Are the inputs always guaranteed to match up 1-to-1 like that?

Comment: and you have attempted...?

Comment: No,its just an example...i have ranges that are very big @user2357112

Comment: Is `file2` the output file, or another input file? Not sure whether you want to print the middle value between the two, or check if the corresponding value in `file2` is between the two numbers in the range.

Comment: file2 is another file with values that are between the file1 @F3AR3DLEGEND

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do something with the results other than print them out, you can create a dictionary that maps ranges (from file1) to numbers within those ranges (from file2.)

```
ranges = []
with open('file1') as f:
    for line in f:
        ranges.append(line.strip().split(' '))
ranges = [tuple(int(_) for _ in r) for r in ranges]
in_range = {range_: set() for range_ in ranges}
with open('file2') as f:
    for line in f:
        num = int(line.strip())
        for range_ in ranges:
            if range_[0] < num < range_[1] # Between low and high
                in_range.add(num)
# print in_range
```

Comment: I got this error when i tried to run on example Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fi.py", line 5, in <module>
    in_range = {range_: set() for range_ in ranges}
  File "fi.py", line 5, in <dictcomp>
    in_range = {range_: set() for range_ in ranges}
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' @Chris Barker

Comment: in just want to print the output of numbers that are between the file1 range values @Chris Barker

Comment: The only reason you can't make a set of these `range_` values is that each one is a list. You could convert each one to a tuple—e.g., `{tuple(range_): set() for range_ in ranges}` to fix that.

Comment: Meanwhile, you probably want to convert the values in each `range_` to numbers at some point, because `'10' < num < '20'` will either always be false (Python 2.x) or raise a `TypeError` (Python 3.x), but `10 < num < 20` will be true for 11 through 19 and false for any other number.

Comment: @abh: Those two problems (and possibly others) aside, this is a good start that you could use to try to build a working program out of for yourself. If you don't understand what it's doing, ask. If you do understand what it's doing, and try to finish it, but get stuck somewhere, then you'll have a good, easily-answerable question instead of the "someone write the code for vaguely-defined problem for me" question that you currently have.

Comment: Thank you@abarnert.i made it worked which i edited above

Answer (score 0):

In Python, here's how to…

Open a file:

```
with open('thefile.txt') as f:
```

Iterate the lines of a file:

```
for line in f:
```

Throw away extra whitespace at the end of a line:

```
line = line.rstrip()
```

Split each line in two around the first block of whitespace:

```
left, right = line.split(None, 1)
```

Convert a string to a number:

```
low = int(low)
```

Get the number halfway between two other numbers:

```
mid = (low + high) // 2
```

Or, to check whether a number is between two other numbers:

```
if low <= mid <= high:
```

Print a formatted result:

```
print('{} is the value between {} and {}'.format(mid, low, high))
```

Of course you also want some error handling, and you have to put the whole thing together, but that should be enough to finish it yourself.

Comment: i dont want the mid numbers..its was an example.the file2 may have different numbers like if a range is 1000-1200 and in other file i have 1129 which is in between i want to get that @abarnert

Comment: @abh: OK, I'll add one more bit.

Comment: where do i open the 2 file? @abarnert

Comment: You can open both of them at the top by, e.g., writing `with open('file1.txt') as f1, open('file2.txt') as f2:`. Or you can nest the `with` and loop over `file2.txt` inside the loop over `file1.txt`, or vice-versa. Or you can process one file into a useful data structure, as in Chris Barker's answer, and then process the other file in a separate loop. I'm not trying to write your code for you, I'm just trying to give you enough pieces to get started, and then tell us where you're stuck. That's the only way you're going to end up with code you understand, and can maintain and expand on.

Answer (score -1):

This should do the trick:

```
with open('file1.txt') as file1, open('file2.txt') as file2:
    ranges = [line.split(' ') for line in file1 if line.rstrip()]
    values = filter(lambda line: bool(line.rstrip()), file2.readlines())
for value, _range in zip(values, ranges):
    print("{} is {}the value between {} and {}".format(value, "not " if int(_range[0]) <= float(value) <= float(_range[1]) else "", _range[0], _range[1])
```

Comment: Why call `readlines()`? `for line in file1` does the exact same thing, but without wasting resources and readability.

Comment: Also, `if line` isn't going to help you here, because `'\n'` is not empty.

Comment: That's not very readable. Particularly the 153-character line.

Comment: Also, `lambda line: bool(line)` is a really confusing way of writing `bool`, and it's going to have the same problem as above, with `'\n'` not being falsey.

Comment: `line != '\n'` is a really, really bad idea, unless you're explicitly trying to make sure it fails on Windows text files.